# How to draw a line with absolute coordinates in Plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

How can I draw a vertical line, which is 3cm long and 15cm apart from the left side of the paper at the top of the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In plain TeX?

Comment: @JohnKormylo you have `ovelay` in your comment, I'm sure you meant `overlay` and the file would need to have `\input tikz`. Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *top of the page*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain e-TeX solution.  Adjustments will be needed for non-zero `\hoffset` or `\voffset`.

```
\headline={%
  \vbox to 0pt{
    \vskip\dimexpr-1in+22.5pt-8.5pt\relax
    \hbox to 0pt{\kern\dimexpr-1in+15cm\relax
      \vrule height 3cm\relax
      \hss}}}
Hello World!
\bye
```

If you don't want to sacrifice `\headline` for this, you might also redefine `\makeheadline` (this is even true Knuth TeX).

```
\def\makeheadline{
  \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{\hskip-1in\hskip15cm \vrule depth 3cm \hss}
  \ht0=0pt \dp0=0pt
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-1in \box0 \vss}
  % orignal \makeheadline follows
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-22.5pt
    \line{\vbox to 8.5pt{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
Hello World!
\bye
```

> [image]

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming John Kormylo has rightly understood exactly where you want the line, this is how you do it in Plain TeX:

```
\input tikz.tex
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw (current page.north west) ++(15cm,0) -- ++(0,-3cm);}
\bye
```